# Proper use of a word in the sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Ok, I’m doing a story and I’m very confused about how to properly say the sentence. “I’m willing to do so Love. But, what entices you to want such a desire like that?” I’m 12th grade English in reading and writing, but my grammar always needs help. Can you guys please help me with this sentence?

Comment: That last question doesn't make any sense. _Want_ and _desire_ mean the same thing. And _entice_ has to do with flirtation or dissipation. What in the world is being asked?

Comment: ...but what has brought on such a desire?

Comment: Also "such a desire like that" is badly formed. The correct formation is either "a desire like that" or, more formally and less idiomatically "such a desire as that".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, look up the word entice in the dictionary and try and work out where you’ve gone wrong.

I’ll break it down further for you, if you’d like.

First sentence:

> I’m willing to do so, love.

I assume you’re using a capital letter for ‘love’ because it’s a pet name or colloquial? Nevertheless, you wouldn’t use a capital letter; and in that sentence you would put a comma beforehand.

Second sentence:

> You never want to start a sentence with ‘but’, unless you really know what you’re doing.

I’m afraid that ‘...entices you to want...’ is nonsensical.

My advice would be to put the two sentences together thus:

> I’m willing to do so love, but why do these desires entice you so?

Notice that there’s no comma before “love” in the sentence I’ve written because I’ve broken it up differently.